# TFS 2012 Team Alerts do not work

Tags: tfs

I've installed TFS 2012 Update 1 and set up email alerts in application tier in TFS admin console. After that I added few test accounts to project's team and set-up some default Team Alerts (like 'when a work item is assigned to me'), all through web access.

Problem is that nobody is receiving any emails, however when users subscribe to those same alerts individually under My Alerts, everything is working fine. Did anybody experienced anything like this? I didn't find any errors in the event viewer.

Comment: You have to subscribe to an alert to get an alert.

Comment: You had to in TFS 2010, but TFS 2012 introduces new feature called Team Alerts, where admin can set those up, after which every team member should be receiveing email alerts whitout any subscription steps on his/her side.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem happen when it concatenates all emails together, so try to make sure all names are straightforward without any apostrophe or special characters, try to have only one member and test and start increasing the number of members each time with test till you get your problem.