# TFS 2012 - Team alerts are not sent

Tags: tfs

I've followed previous conversations on this matter but none work for my case.
[TFS 2012 Team Alerts not sending emails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14566315/tfs-2012-team-alerts-not-sending-emails)

Can you please recommend on additional steps or configurations which need to set ?

Thanks
Doron

Comment: Can you describe what you've tried so far? And what your current settings are?

Answer (score 0):

Please run the following SQL statement on you TFS configuration database to get more information:

```
SELECT  StartTime, Result, ResultMessage 
FROM [Tfs_Configuration].[dbo].[tbl_JobHistory]
WHERE JobId = 'A4804DCF-4BB6-4109-B61C-E59C2E8A9FF7'
AND Result <> 0 
ORDER BY StartTime DESC
```

Some other points that you could check:

- Personal notifications are working?
- Did you added the users to the TeamProjects Team? This is not done by default.
- Do you have Active Directory and enabled default email addresses?