# TFS 2013 (Update 2) Team Alerts not sending emails

Tags: email, tfs

I've followed the discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14566315/tfs-2012-team-alerts-not-sending-emails) and I do have a similar case **right after I applied Update-2 to TFS 2013 (Update-1)**. NOTE: Everything used to work fine prior the upgrade.

- Personal alerts **DO** work, so it is not an obvious SMTP server error.
- Team alerts **DO NOT** work.
- TFS 2013 **IS CONNECTED** to Active Directory.
- All users have email addresses.
- No errors whatsoever in event viewer.

I would appreciate the help. Thanks.

Comment: I'm also having this issue (team alerts don't work but personal ones do).  I checked the TFS admin email settings and noticed that the SMTP server port was empty for some reason, so I put the default in (25) but it didn't appear to make a difference.  I will continue to investigate and post an answer if I find a solution.

Comment: @Jubblerbug Thank you for your response. Check my answer below and see if it is applicable in your case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think I figured out what is happening. It all boils down to this: **Teams who are not part of Contributors group are not able to receive email notifications.**

This behavior is new and was introduced in Update 2 (Update 1 used to work fine).

More discussion about this can be found [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6f8d29f8-b213-4b95-b74d-eab572314136/tfs-2013-update-2-team-alerts-not-sending-emails?forum=tfsadmin&prof=required)

Also, I filled a bug report to Microsoft Connect Feedback [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/850897/tfs-2013-update-2-team-alerts-not-sending-emails)

Comment: You have made my Friday! I went into TFS administration, made the team a member of the contributors group and it started working...   Now I've got to do another 50 projects, but thanks again for sharing this fix!

Comment: Thank you so much for this. The workaround, as mentioned on the MS Connect site, is to add your Team Group to the Contributors group.

Comment: In my case e-mail alerts didn't work at all. Not even to myself. After I added another **Team**-Member to the Team Project (additional to myself), it started working.