# TFS 2013 (update 4) email alerts for team without contributor role

Tags: tfs

I'm on update 4. I want to let business users submit "tickets" in TFS for research. However, they less rights to the project and aren't part of the contributors role. In addition, TFS documention indicates that once you deploy a "team alert" that the "@ME" variable changes to actually referring to the team, and not the person.

What is the approach to take to ensure that someone with less permissions, and not part of contributor group, will always get notified when a work item they created gets changed.

**NOTE: TFS 2013 UPDATE 4 -- ON PREMISE**

Related item: [TFS 2013 (Update 2) Team Alerts not sending emails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22900091/tfs-2013-update-2-team-alerts-not-sending-emails)
* this doesn't help as I can't add them as contributors, need narrowing security permission.

## UPDATE 2016-02-22

In looking through the alerts section, as an admin I see I can actually search and find an individual and setup an alert for them on the workitem change. However, this is a manual process, and I would like to do this in bulk. I will work on tracing the query execution that is called when the alert is created and see if I could replicate with a sql command to insert alerts for all users. However, I'd like to avoid running a direct sql query to do this if possible, if there is some bulk processing functionality that allows an individual alert to be deployed to each person on a team without doing it manually.

Anyone aware of any extensions, scripts, or other functionality that does this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the comments of this issue [TFS 2013 Update 2 Team Alerts not sending emails](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/850897/tfs-2013-update-2-team-alerts-not-sending-emails).This issue is not fixed with TFS 2013 UPDATE4. So, if you can't add the users as contributors, then they can't receive an email.

As a workaround, you can use events of team room. Adding events lets your team know when builds finish, source code is checked in, work items are updated, and requests for code reviews occur. This can be visible to all members of the team room. Detailed steps and more info from MSDN [Collaborate in a team room](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vs/alm/work/productivity/collaborate-in-a-team-room)
[image]

Comment: @Chamerlain thanks for the response. The team room probably won't work for us at this time, and I've found it to be too wide in focus, as in all alerts, which basically does the same as team alerts. My goal is to have each person having their own individual email alert for items that they created.