# TFS 2018 Email Notifications not sending out

Tags: tfs

I have been working on a new TFS 2018 install and I have everything setup with the exception of email notifications. I setup in the admin console the SMTP relay information and when i click test and enter in my email, I get the test notification. Now when i switch to the TFS web console and I create a new work item and assign it to a user the user never gets an email. I have verified that the team notification are on and there is a notification setup for when a work item is assigned. Is there something Im missing, is there a log I need to enable to show if there are errors sending emails out?

any help would be great.

Comment: What about other subscriptions? e.g create a subscription to trigger the alert when a work item changed, etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, please make sure you have created the subscriptions correctly and the SMTP server is OK. See [Manage notifications for a team](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-tw/vsts/collaborate/manage-team-notifications?toc=/vsts/notifications/toc.json&bc=/vsts/notifications/breadcrumb/toc.json).

Based on my test, **teams who are not part of Contributors group are not able to receive email notifications**.

So, if your project team is not a member of the **Contributors** group, just add the team to the group. Then try it again.

Another workaround is using the email address directly when creating the subscriptions. This should be related to the AD sync issue. Refer to [**this thread**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14566315/tfs-2012-team-alerts-not-sending-emails) for details: .

> Without Active Directory, TFS will not send team alerts. Users can set
>   their preferred email address, which TFS will then sync to Active
>   Directory as the "[Member's default email address]". If no Active
>   Directory is found, that sync won't work, which means their default
>   email is blank. Blank email means no alert sent (which means no error
>   about the sending failing either).

[image]

Comment: Thanks the contributor was the issue, we have some custom groups and they weren't in there.